# Hibernate spring: multiple datasources with many to many?

Tags: hibernate, spring, hibernate-mapping

I know it's possible to use multiple sessionfactories but since I have a many to many relationship where one of the tables is in another schema(and it's unlikely the first schema user will get the rights on the second schema) I need to find a way to map this.

Is this even possible, or will I need to try and convince the DBA to grant to first user rights on the second schema?

Comment: Convince the dba, you are trying to get data which you are not authorized to access. You should be granted to retrieve it.

Comment: They gave me a second user which is authorized to access it for "administrative" reasons.

Answer (score 1):

By design, each session factory uses one set of database properties: host, schema/db, user, password. Using two different credentials (as is your case) means using  two different session factories. So, you don't have much hope here.

But there's another solution, outside of Hibernate. You can use [Teiid](http://www.jboss.org/teiid) to connect to the two data sources and provide a single data interface for Hibernate. See more details [here](http://docs.jboss.org/teiid/7.0.0/client-developers-guide/en-US/html/using_hibernate.html)